# Why 3 references with python literals?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
... 
>>> sys.getrefcount(Foo())
1
>>> sys.getrefcount(12323451234.121213)
3
>>> sys.getrefcount(12323451234)
3
>>> sys.getrefcount("Hello")
3
```

I am amused by this situation. Apparently literals (even those who are brought into existence on the spot) have a refcount of three. Why is that?

Comment: Yeah, it's a dupe. Please close.